# Wordpress - PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_bloginfo()

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error

I'm integrating an external script with my wordpress theme and I'm getting this error in one of my files:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_bloginfo()

this script is located in

> themes/mytheme/myscript

And all files are included as following:

```
include(WP_CONTENT_DIR."/themes/mytheme/myscript/myfile.php");
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: Where (which file) are you including them?

Comment: @naththedeveloper I mean subfiles in my /script/ folder have relation and are included like that, each other.

Comment: In your included files, is there a get_bloginfo() function definition ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you must include wp-blog-header.php in your main php
like this

```
require WP_DIR.'/wp-blog-header.php';
```

being WP_DIR the main wp directory

Answer (score 6):

The issue is usually `mysql` related...you need to reset your `wordpress db user password`.
That is to say that the `password` for the database user for `wordpress` has expired and you don't know about it.
Either do a `linux command-line`

```
mysql -uroot -p
SET PASSWORD FOR <WPUSERNAME>@localhost = PASSWORD('whateveryouwant');
```

Or through `phpmyadmin` - `users` tab -> `Edit privileges` -> `Change password`

Comment: thats correct. related to mysql config file. wp-config file check db name or db password of other configurations in wp-config or mysql db name dictation

Comment: Why would not being able to find a method in a class be related to a database password.  That makes no sense to me.  function get_bloginfo()

Answer (score 3):

Please see this question:
[Wordpress php fatal error: Call to undefined function language_attributes()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010586/wordpress-php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-language-attributes)

Make sure you have wp-config.php configured with the correct DB info.

Answer (score 1):

Open wp-config.php and go to your plesk/cpanel and make sure database name and user and password are the same. In my case, I had a wrong database password set! So I updated it to match the one in wp-config.php and that solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and none of the above worked. finally, I run `wp-cli db repair` and the problem was solved. for more information about installing and using wp-cli see their [website](https://wp-cli.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Here How I Solved my Problem. Thanks to [@adam allalou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10802569/adam-allalou)

Step 1: press: `Ctrl + f`

Step 2: then in the search bar type `Intelephense: Stubs`

Step 3: Scroll down and click `add item`

Step 4: then chose `wordpress`

[image]